# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unmask' of undefined at Receiver.unmask

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

Launch karma in chrome browser and abru[tly close itself with an Error while running karma for unit testing in angular 2 :

> 19 04 2017 19:14:27.848:ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'unmask' of undefined
>       at Receiver.unmask (C:\Projects\Git Repo\TDP\switchmanager\src\SwitchDesigner\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:306:46)
>       at Receiver.finish (C:\Projects\Git Repo\TDP\switchmanager\src\SwitchDesigner\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:505:25)
>       at Receiver.expectHandler (C:\Projects\Git Repo\TDP\switchmanager\src\SwitchDesigner\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:493:33)
>       at Receiver.add (C:\Projects\Git Repo\TDP\switchmanager\src\SwitchDesigner\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:103:24)
>       at Socket.realHandler (C:\Projects\Git Repo\TDP\switchmanager\src\SwitchDesigner\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:825:20)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

as per: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1010
please add `bufferutil` as a dependency.

Comment: Hey Ahmed thanks for taking some time out, but I have already included the buffer util as dependencies. "bufferutil": "^3.0.0",

Comment: The link suggests v1 or v2 are compatible wit ws@>=2.0.2. What version of ws are you using? Also, if you can setup a simple app with the issue, and upload it to github, we can try and debug to help you.